# Is there a way to save state in Flutter so the App starts off from where we left off?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, flutter-state

I want data to be persistence. I want the state to be same from where I left off before closing the app. Is there a way to achieve this in flutter?

Answer (score 2):

I dont know this is the right solution for this, but maybe you can save the last pages path to [sharedpreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences) every time user navigates to a page, then when your app is opening, read the last page from shared preferences and navigate to that page.